# When using a screwdriver tester i am completing the circuit with 110v?

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

if i use a screwdriver tester, i am part of the circuit with 110v passing my body? isn't this dangerous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the screwdriver tester works by weak capacitive coupling to ground through your hand. the amount of current involved is far too small to be lethal, or even to feel in your fingers.

Comment: so is low current and low voltage?

Comment: The voltage to ground is 110V, the current is very low.

Comment: yes, thats is what i mean, isn't a problem with 110v but a very low current?

Comment: see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/miccur.html . Low current means that the electrons in the wire are barely drifting, The 110 exist at the socket but the air around the live has no current due to the large resistance of air. The tester is made with such a large resistance that only a very  tiny current occurs that allows for the light in the detecting element but barely moves through you.